# Contagem De Tempo Para Jogada (Threads)

Tags: c#, multithreading

O necessário para responder a pergunta está em comentários no código:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        player1.Start();
        t.Start();

        while (t.IsAlive); //A intenção seria depois que o Thread t acabar se a Thread player1 
                            //ainda estiver ativa o jogador perde a rodada.
                            //gostaria também de que se a Thread player1 já acabou
                            //a Thread t pode se encerrar.
        if (player1.IsAlive) player1.Abort(); Console.Write("\nSeu Tempo Acabou");
    }

    static void player()
    {
        Console.Write("Player1 Escreva Algo (Nao Deixe Passar 10 Segundos): ");
        str += Console.ReadLine() + " ";
        Console.Write(" {0}", str);
    }

    static void tempo()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); //10 sec = 10.000 milisec
    }

    static String str = "";
    static System.Threading.Thread player1 = new System.Threading.Thread(player);
    static System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(tempo);

}
```

Ex: Em jogos de xadrez você tem um tempo disponível para movimentar sua peça, se você não movimentar dentro de por exemplo 30 segundos você perde sua jogada e é a vez do próximo jogador (Ai mostraria a mensagem), agora se você movimentar sua peça antes do tempo, você apenas passa a vez para outro jogador sem perder nada. a ideia é +/- essa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voltei no código e percebi que foi só mudar a função `void player()` que funcionou exatamente como eu queria, então ficou assim:

```
static void player()
{
    Console.Write("Player1 Escreva Algo (Nao Deixe Passar 10 Segundos): ");
    str += Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("\"{0}\"", str);
    t.Abort();
}
```

E também mudei isso:

```
while (t.IsAlive);
if (player1.IsAlive) { player1.Abort(); Console.Write("\nSeu Tempo Acabou"); }
```

Para isso:

```
while (t.IsAlive);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
if (player1.IsAlive) { player1.Abort(); Console.Write("\nSeu Tempo Acabou"); }
```

Quando ocorre `t.Abort()` na Thread player1 o `while(t.IsAlive)` da Thread da main é encerrado.

Porque quando ele saia do `while (t.IsAlive);` e ia para: `if (player1.IsAlive)`
não sei porque player1 continuava Alive mesmo depois de passar da linha `t.Abort();` ai quando chega no `if (player1.IsAlive)` ele validava como true, sendo que player1 já tinha acabado.
Ai resolvi colocando 1 milissegundo entre o while e o if.

Mas também gostei muito das outras respostas, coloquei a minha aqui só para mostrar mais uma saída.

Answer (score 3):

Usando a classe [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) é fácil fazer o que pretende:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String str = null;

        //Objectos que permitem cancelar as Tasks
        var tokenSourceTempo = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var ctTempo = tokenSourceTempo.Token;
        var tokenSourcePlayer = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var ctPlayer = tokenSourcePlayer.Token;

        //Cria a task que espera 10 segundos até 
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);

                if (ctTempo.IsCancellationRequested != true)
                {
                    tokenSourcePlayer.Cancel(); //Cancela a task player
                    Console.Write("\nSeu Tempo Acabou\n");
                }
            }, ctTempo);

        //Cria a task player
        var taskPlayer = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                var key = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

                Console.Write("Player1 Escreva Algo (Nao Deixe Passar 10 Segundos): ");

                while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)//Aceita teclas até a tecla enter ser usada
                {

                    key = Console.ReadKey();
                    ctPlayer.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();//Se a task player foi cancelada aborta
                    tokenSourceTempo.Cancel();//O player teclou algo, cancela task tempo
                    str += key.KeyChar;//Constroi string
                }

            }, ctPlayer);

        try
        {
            taskPlayer.Wait();// Espera enquanto o player tecla algo
            Console.Write("\nVocê escreveu: {0}\n", str);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)//Quando a task player é cancelada é lançada uma Exception
        {
            if (taskPlayer.IsCanceled)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Você terá agora de ajustar às suas necessidades.
Utilize <kbd>ctrl+F5</kbd> para testar se tiver a utilizar o Visual Studio.

Comment: Não sei se isso realmente serve é pq to meio confuso para mim mas, para min está parecendo que sempre depois que passar os 10 segundos ele vai mostrar "\nSeu Tempo Acabou" eu quero que isto só aparece se o jogador não digitar nada.

Comment: Não tinha entendido isso assim. Vou editar a resposta. O que quer que aconteça depois do jogador digitar algo?

Comment: Bom só faça o seguinte se o usuário informar algo beleza coloque em str e feche o programa, se ele não informar nada em 10 segundos diga que seu tempo acabou e pause o programa com um ReadLine() e depois feche.

Comment: Como eu trataria o caso em que por exemplo o player tecla algo e depois apaga ? neste caso também deveria ser mostrada a mensagem.

Comment: Descobri um bug mt loco kkkk se você digitar por exemplo asd e depois ir apertando backspace ate fazer com que o cursor chegue na palavra 'player1' depois é só vim apertando a setinha para a direita e ver acontecer kkk

Comment: Para isso teríamos de usar `Console.ReadLine()` em vez de `Console.ReadKey();`. Nessa situação só será considerado que o jogador digitou algo após este teclar ***enter***, ou seja, o tempo está contando até ser teclado ***enter***

Answer (score 1):

Bom, criei algumas classes para ficar mais fácil de se entender.
Os comentários lhe ajudarão a entender o fluxo.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Pt.Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // nova partida
            var match = new Match(new Player("Player 1"), 60);

            //Ação customizada que será executada quando o usuário digitar algum texto
            match.OnPlayerInput += input =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usuário escreveu: \"{0}\"", input);
                match.Finish();
            };

            //Ação customizada que será executada quando a partida for encerrada, 
            //ou seja, por tempo ou pela chamada do método Finish() e não pelo fechamento da Aplicação.
            match.OnMatchEnd += () => Console.WriteLine("Tchau!");

            match.Start();
        }
    }

    class Match
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Tempo em segundos.
        /// </summary>
        public uint Time { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Player atual
        /// </summary>
        public Player CurrentPlayer { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Chamado quando o usuário escreve algo.
        /// </summary>
        public event Action<string> OnPlayerInput;
        /// <summary>
        /// Chamado quando a partida termina.
        /// </summary>
        public event Action OnMatchEnd;

        private AutoResetEvent _autoEvent;
        private TimerCallback _tick;
        private Timer _timer;
        private readonly Thread _matchThread;

        private const int AGORA = 0, SEGUNDO = 1000, MINUTO = 60000;

        /// <summary>
        /// Criar uma nova partida
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="player">Jogador atual</param>
        /// <param name="time">Tempo da partida</param>
        public Match(Player player, uint time) {
            CurrentPlayer = player; 
            Time = time;

            _matchThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">> {0} Escreva Algo (Nao Deixe Passar 10 Segundos): ", player.Name);
                On_PlayerInput(Console.ReadLine());
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inicia a partida
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            if (Time == 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Esta partida já foi encerrada.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                return;
            }

            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            // Usado para fazer com que o timer seja repetido.
            _autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            // Callback do Timer
            _tick = Tick;
            // Timer disparado imediatamente e chamado a cada segundo
            _timer = new Timer(_tick, _autoEvent, AGORA, SEGUNDO);

            //Capturar do input do usuário
            _matchThread.Start();

            Console.WriteLine(">> Partida Iniciada.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Termina a partida
        /// </summary>
        public void Finish()
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
            _autoEvent.Dispose();
            Time = 0;

            if (OnMatchEnd != null) OnMatchEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(">> Partida concluída.");
            Console.Read();
            _matchThread.Abort();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Chamado a cada segundo passado
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stateInfo"></param>
        private void Tick(Object stateInfo)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(">> Tempo atual da partida: {0}s", Time);
            if (--Time == 0) Finish();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Chamado quando o usuário digitar um texto (após apertar Enter)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">Texto digitado</param>
        private void On_PlayerInput(string input)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(">> Usuário escreveu: {0}", (CurrentPlayer.Input = input));
            if (OnPlayerInput != null) OnPlayerInput(input);
        }
    }

    class Player
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Nome do jogador
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Texto digitado pelo jogador
        /// </summary>
        public string Input { get; set; }

        public Player(string name) { Name = name; }
    }
}
```